# regex getting the first instance of a number from a string

Tags: java, regex

I return the following string from a webpage

```
Order Number: 1509596 Customer Number: 8
```

but it could also be

```
Order ID 1509596 Customer 8
```

I want to use regex so in my method I just return the order number, I was doing

```
orderNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")
```

but that obviously doesn't work because I then have an 8 on the end of my order number. Can somebody help me how I would just the order number as I'm rubbish at reg ex!

The string will always be 50 characters long but the order number is dynamic so I don't know how long it will be, is it possible to just return the first number in the string?

Comment: You should be able to use the "[0-9]+" regex to match the first number in your string.

Comment: Would be better to do a regex match on sequences of numbers, and select the index of the one you want. If you continue the way you are doing it, this regex could work... `Customer.+|[^0-9]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a regex that matches the whole input, capturing the part you want, then replace everything captured to "extract" what you want.

```
String firstNumber = str.replaceAll("^\\D*(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/lkggQq).

The regex matches all leading non-digits (if any), then as many digits as are found next as capture group 1, then matches to the end. `$1` is a *back reference* to capture group 1.

---

If newlines (which dot does not match by default) are in the input, enable DOTALL flag by adding `(?s)` to the regex:

```
String firstNumber = str.replaceAll("(?s)^\\D*(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Comment: When new line exist on string, this method not work correctly.

Comment: @SaeidZ See edited answer for how to cater for newline characters.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a single line that would accomplish this, but the following should work:

```
String orderString = "Order Number: 1509596 Customer Number: 8";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(orderString);
if (m.find())
{
  String orderNr = m.group();
  System.out.println(orderNr);
}
```

Comment: Can't think of how to do it in one line? [See this... muhahahaha](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21427608/regex-getting-the-first-instance-of-a-number-from-a-string/21427741#21427741)

Comment: You can simply use `String orderNr = m.group()`

Comment: @BackSlash: thank, I thought `group()` could only be used when there were explicit groups (using `(..)`) in the regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you change `orderNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")`

to

`orderNumber.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ",")` hence

you will get `,1509596,8` as an answer,

I think this is probably help you to solve ans.